# What is the best way to save a 1 line variable in a tomcat setup?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am needing to save a 1 line variable, it is just a simple date. This needs to be saved through server restarts etc. I was just wondering what the best way to do this was. I could create a whole DB table for this one variable but I thought that seemed a bit overkill.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Will you save it on run time (will it be changing) or is this something you'll preset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save it or just configure it?

If you want to just configure it, you can use an init parameter in the web.xml.

If you want to save it (show a form and persist it later), you should look at java.util.Preferences. That would likely work fine, but it would be "global", i.e. across all instances of Tomcat (not that it's likely an issue in this case).

Comment: My only other question would be, do these variables persist through deployments?

Comment: Yea, they will. They're stored in the Windows Registry or in a local file based on the user that runs the program on Unix (stored in their home directory). That's also why they're "global", all instances of Java can see the same value.